# Use a select html tag + javascript to use as filter

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple html + jquery structure to show/hide html elements.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" name="showall">Show All</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="showblue">Show Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" name="showred">Show Red</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="filters">
  <li class="blue">Blue</li>
  <li class="red">Red</li>
  <li class="red blue">Red and Blue</li>
</ul>

<script>
  $("a[name='showall']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".filters li").show();
  });
  $("a[name='showblue']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(".filters li:not(.blue)").hide();
    $(".filters li.blue").show();
  });
  $("a[name='showred']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(".filters li:not(.red)").hide();
    $(".filters li.red").show();
  });
</script>
```

See working example at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vicmontol/Qs5N7/)

I want to change the filter system from my `<a>` tags to a more efficent space-saver for RWD `SELECT` tag and show/hide the html elements when the `<option>` is selected (change event ??).

Don't know if it is possible to do with minimal markup + js, or if I need a `<form>` and AJAX based solution to do it. (based on option value? maybe on change event?)

Any clues? Tried a few but I'm not on JS :( Thank you so much for the help.

P.S Edited with world's fastest solution thanks to BeNdErR:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="all">Show All</option>
  <option value="blue">Show Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Show Red</option>
</select>
<script>
  $("#mySelect").on("change", function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  console.log(value);
  if(value != "all"){
    $(".filters li:not(." + value + ")").hide();
    $(".filters li." + value ).show();
    return;
  }
  $(".filters li").show();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: so you want a dropdown filter?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qs5N7/3/ like this?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, with minimal markup. Thank you, @BeNdErR